# mustache in vue not work

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I created a component and used it with vue-router. However, when I update the webpage it told me that "the data 'sss' is not defined."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IIFE.png)

and this is my component:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCXIA.png)

I am sure that I have already define the data. so what's wrong?

Comment: sorry, the data 'author' in the first picture actually is the 'sss'...I just changed the name

Comment: Please add code instead of image of code.

Comment: ok...........................I will never do it again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have a type, it's `data` not `deta`

Also for future reference please copy and paste your code, don't post screen shots otherwise we will have to type everything out if your question requires an answer with the code.

Comment: I see..Sorry, I have no idea about the rules of stack overflow.